# Postgres 9.4+ split an alpha numeric string into two columns

Tags: string, postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.4

I need to deal with the following and after searching I wasn't able to find  exactly what I'm looking for:

Let's say I have a column which may or may not have an alphanumeric string

```
SKU
-----
12345ABC
12345-Abc
12345-Ab23
12345
```

Which I would like to break into

```
SKU   | BATCH
------------------
12345 | ABC
12345 | Abc
12345 | Ab23
12345 | NULL
```

using PostgreSQL 9.4+  I've tried the `string` and `sub_string` method's but I'm not getting the results I'm looking to achieve... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [substring function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

```
with a (SKU) as (values('12345ABC'), ('12345-Abc'), ('12345-Ab23'), ('12345'))
select substring(sku from '^\d+'), substring(sku from '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$') from a;

 substring | substring 
-----------+-----------
 12345     | ABC
 12345     | Abc
 12345     | Ab23
 12345     | 
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thnx this helped. I didn't have the correct `REGEXP_MATCH` item

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_matches:

```
with a (SKU) as (values('12345ABC'), ('12345-Abc'), ('12345-Ab23'), ('12345'))
select res[1], res[2]
from (
    SELECT regexp_matches(SKU, '(\d+)[^[:alnum:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)?')     res 
    FROM a
) y;
```